# Change background of one row of a GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview, background

I have a `GridView` within a `ListView` in WPF. The `ListView` (and `GridView` columns) have a bound `ObservableCollection` that populates them.

How can I change the background of one row of the `GridView`, given the index in the `ObservableCollection`? I need to do this programmatically, in C#.

```
<ListView Margin="12,39,0,0" Name="Library" DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding _songData}" Height="681" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseDoubleClick="Library_MouseDoubleClick"  ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContextMenu}" AlternationCount="2" Background="AliceBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="846">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="gvLibrary">
                <!--<GridViewColumn Width="20" Header="hi" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding isSongPlaying}" x:Name="gvColumnPlaying" />-->
                <GridViewColumn Width="220" Header="Title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" x:Name="gvColumnTitle" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="180" Header="Artist" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Artist}" x:Name="gvColumnArtist" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="180" Header="Album" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Album}" x:Name="gvColumnAlbum" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="180" Header="Location" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Location}" x:Name="gvColumnLocation" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="80" Header="File Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Ext}" x:Name="gvColumnFileType" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Do you want to change it in your ViewModel, or just in code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a `Style` and a `DataTrigger`. First add an `IsSelected` property on the class of items contained in the `ListView`:

```
public class Song : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private bool _IsSelected;
    public bool IsSelected 
    {
        get { return _IsSelected; }
        set
        {
            _IsSelected = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Then apply the style to your `ListViewItem`s:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Now, whenever your programmatically set the IsSelected property, the corresponding row will be highlighted:

```
_songData[5].IsSelected = true;
```